# keyboard hide the ion-input field iOS Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, keyboard, ionic3

When I click on the last `ion-input`, `ion-input` display below the keyboard this is my HTML field

```
<ion-list>
<ion-label> Conveyance
        </ion-label>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="modelfirst.conveyance"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-label> HRA
        </ion-label>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="modelfirst.hra"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-label> Interest Paid on Home Loan
      </ion-label>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="modelfirst.home_loan"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Everything working on an Android device but not working in iOS if any kind of help let me know.

Comment: Are you using simulator ? or real device

Comment: i am using real device

Comment: i try this but not working @ManojBhardwaj

Comment: ok  just adding a code to app.scss it will work for you
.scroll-content { padding-bottom: 0!important; }

Comment: thank for replay i already add  .scroll-content { padding-bottom: 0!important; }  in app.scss file but still not resolve my issues

Comment: i have last option for you imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
scrollAssist: true,
autoFocusAssist: true
})
],

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj thank for your replay i will try and let you know